# Excel vba open temporary file called 'book1' while copying the workbook from the selected path

Tags: excel, vba

while working on  Excel vba to copy the selected worksheet from selected path , VBA opening  same sheets in the temporary file called 'book1' while copying.Further i am manually closing the file

This is the code i am following in my program

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename)
wb.Worksheets(1).Copy 
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: my request is opening the excel file from path and imported the records to sql database.for that i am using that above code. however file is opened at that same time same file opened as 'Book1' is also opened...that the problem